# Does Elixir have a garbage collector?

Tags: elixir

I've started reading about the Elixir programming language.

I understand that:

1. It is Functional
2. It is dynamic but support @spec
3. It is based on Erlang VM

My question is: Does it have a sort of GC?

Comment: Side note: `@spec`s are **annotations**, they're not understood by the Elixir compiler (or the Erlang one). They're mainly used by a static analyzer called [dialyzer](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dialyzer.html).

Comment: for example ... if a get a list of strings from network and then I consume it in a pure function what happens when the function return? Are this list destroyed immediatly or is destroyed by a sort of GC?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, Erlang has GC, and since Elixir is built on Erlang it too has GC. See this old SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221907/garbage-collection-and-memory-management-in-erlang) about Erlang GC and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888599/does-beam-the-erlang-vm-do-garbage-collection-in-parallel) one. The Elixir site refers to GC as follows:

> Due to their lightweight nature, it is not uncommon to have hundreds
>   of thousands of processes running concurrently in the same machine.
>   Isolation allows processes to be garbage collected independently,
>   reducing system-wide pauses, and using all machine resources as
>   efficiently as possible (vertical scaling).

Comment: also in elixir you can visualise the garbage as it is being collected if you start up :observer.start() and watch the graphs as your program is running.